# How to make Koa.js and Vuejs play together?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, koa, koa2

I'm a big fan of koa.js, and previously I have worked on projects where we combined koa with angular and they played nicely together, so I was wondering how about using koa with vue.js (as a more lightweight framework) and see how they perform together, because I didn't see many implementations of these two.

I'm thinking to use Koa.js for the server and route handling, and Vuejs only for front-end (view rendering, data binding etc.), so I wanted to know what are your best practices to design the web-app and how to configure the project build (if that necessary, how to integrate webpack?).

Also, any feedback you can give for these two playing together would be a great help for me.